# use jquery function with in the response of a ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use jquery and i do a ajax call.

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/rest/lodgers/" + lodgerId + "/rentamount";
 jQuery.ajax({
     type: "get",
     url: url,
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {

         data.optionsPrice = data.optionsPrice.replace(".", ",");
     },
     error: function(jqXHR, status) {
         check401Unauthorized(jqXHR);
     }
 });
```

in the success part, replace seem unknow, is there a way to use it?

Comment: try `var myData = data.optionsPrice; myData =  myData.replace(".", ",");` ?

Comment: why don't you look at what is inside optionsPrice? try this: `console.log(data.optionsPrice)`

Comment: why do you think replace is unknown?

Comment: Seems that`replace` was tried to be applied for undefined `optionsPrice`. Check your `data` object in your browser debugger.

Comment: And yes - we can help faster if you share an example of expected object `data`.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score -1):

what is the data type of data.optionsPrice? .replace() will only work with a string.

Assuming data.optionsPrice is not null, you could try this:

```
data.optionsPrice = data.optionsPrice.toString().replace(".", ",");
```

You could also add a null check, just to be sure

```
if(data.optionsPrice!=null)
   data.optionsPrice = data.optionsPrice.replace(".", ",");
```